# How to define output Reg in Chisel properly

Tags: hdl, chisel, register-transfer-level

You may know "output reg" in Verilog, very helpful feature.
But in Chisel I can't find how to do similar things. When I need register output I should do this:

```
package filter

import chisel3._

class TestReg extends Module {
    val io = IO( new Bundle {
        val din  = Input(SInt(32.W))
        val ena  = Input(Bool())
        val dout = Output(SInt())
    })

    val dout = RegInit(0.S(32.W))
    when (io.ena) {
        dout := io.din + 77.S
    }
    io.dout <> dout
}
```

Is there a more "short" way to create output reg?
What I'm looking for is to define Reg in IO bundle and write into it as into register
Something like this:

```
class TestReg extends Module {
    val io = IO( new Bundle {
        val din  = Input(SInt(32.W))
        val ena  = Input(Bool())
        val dout = Output(RegInit(0.S(32.W)))
    })

    when (io.ena) {
        io.dout := io.din + 77.S
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Registers are disallowed in `Bundle` to preserve their purity as interfaces. They're closer to SystemVerilog structs than Verilog 95/2001 port declarations.

With the existing libraries, the easiest way to do what you want is to use [`RegNext`](https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/latest/chisel3/RegNext$.html):

```scala
io.dout := RegNext(io.din + 77.S, 0.S(32.W))
```

Note: that this will not set the width of `io.dout` until the FIRRTL compiler infers the width. This can sometimes cause problems if you ever try to get the width of `io.dout` for something.

Ignoring the standard library, you can also do this more manually by defining your own utility for creating registered connections in one of two possible ways:

1. Create a function to do a "registered" connection

```scala
object ConnectionUtilities {
  def regConnect(lhs: Data, rhs: Data): Unit = {
    val rhsReg = Reg(chiselTypeOf(rhs))
    rhsReg := rhs
    lhs := rhsReg
  }
}
```

With this, you can then use this method for doing connections and generate the necessary register:

```scala
import ConnectionUtilities.regConnect

regConnect(io.out, io.in + 77.S)
```

2. Create an implicit class to add a method to `Data`. This is more advanced and has the potential to confuse people reading your code. However, it lets you extend the Chisel domain specific language with your own domain specific language.

```scala
object ConnectUtilities2 {
  implicit class DataWithRegConnect(lhs: Data) {
    def `:=r` (rhs: Data): Unit = {
      val rhsReg = Reg(chiselTypeOf(rhs))
      rhsReg := rhs
      lhs := rhsReg
    }
  }
}
```

You can then use this new method (noting that this requires the backticks because `:=r` isn't a legal name by itself).

```scala
import ConnectUtilities2.DataWithRegConnect

io.dout `:=r` (io.din + 77.S)
```

Comment: I'd tweak the `RegNext` proposal to use the 2-argument version which supports a reset value like used in the original question: `io.dout := RegNext(io.din + 77.S, 0.S(32.W))`